# Tengo un error de rutas al crear la consulta en php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un error a la hora de establecer la consulta con la base de datos, no me localiza la ruta del archivo config, me salta el error de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de carpetas que tengo en mi proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo conexion.php tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
//ACCEDEMOS A LA DEFINICION DE LAS VARIABLES QUE TENEMOS EN CONFIG.PHP 
require_once("../config/config.php");
class ConexionBD{
    // protected $conexion;
    private static $lastAffectedRows;
    public static function Conexion() :PDO{
    $conexion = null;
            try {
                    $conexion = new PDO(
                        'mysql:host='.HOST.
                        ';dbname='.DB.";charset=utf8",
                         USUARIO, 
                         CLAVE
                        );
                        //Configuramos pdo para que lance excepciones en casos de errores
                    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e)  {
                   echo "No se ha podido conectar a la BBDD, causa PDOException: ".$e- 
 >getMessage();
                   
            }
    return $conexion;      
    }
 
    public static function consulta(string $sql) : PDOStatement | int {
        try {                
            $conexion = self::Conexion(); 
            if (str_starts_with(strtolower(trim($sql)), "select")) {
                $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
            } else {
                $resultado = $conexion->exec($sql); 
            }
            unset($conexion);
            return $resultado;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die("Error en la consulta. ".$ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getLastAffectedRows() : int {
        return self::$lastAffectedRows;
    }
  }

  //aqui comprobamos si la conexion a tenido exito
  $conexion = new ConexionBD();
  if($conexion){
     echo "bien";
  }else{
       echo "mal";
   } 
  ?>
```

El archivo que tiene las variables globales definidas, llamado config.php es el siguiente;

```
<?php
  $servidor= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $path_actual=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $host="localhost";
  $dbname="clinicaveterinaria";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $driver="mysql";

  if(!defined('__CONFIG__')){
     define('__CONFIG__',true);
     define('ROOT_PATH',$servidor);
     define('RUTA_ACTUAL', $path_actual);
     define("HOST",$host);
     define("DB",$dbname);
     define("USUARIO",$username);
     define("CLAVE",$password);
     define("DRIVER",$driver);
     // define('CARPETA_ACTUAL',CARPETA_PADRE.basename(getcwd()).'/');
   }
```

El archivo del cual estoy cogiendo la función  para hacer la consulta es el siguiente, esta funcion llama a la otra funcion que abre una conexion nueva para solicitar los datos a la base de datos:

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");

class RolesModelo{
  function obtenerRolesModelo(){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM ROLES";
    return $this->sentenciaOtenerTodosValores($consulta);
}

function sentenciaOtenerTodosValores($consulta){
     $conexion = new ConexionBD();
     $query = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consulta);
     $query->execute();
     $result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
 }
}
?>
```

El archivo desde el que quiero mostrar los resultados es el siguiente, es un formulario en el cual tiene un campo select, y en los option quiero mostrar los datos que devuelve la consulta a la base de datos:

```
<?php

 require_once('../../modelo/rolesModelo.php');
 $sql= new RolesModelo();
 $sql->obtenerRolesModelo();
 var_dump($sql);
 ?>
 <div id="contenedor">

 <div id="contenedorcentrado" class=" bg-success bg-gradient">
 <div id="register-container">
  <div id="login">
    <h3 class="text-center  text-white">Registro de usuario</h3>
    <form id="loginform">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="usuario">Nombre del Usuario</label></td>
          <td> <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre del 
     usuario" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

AQUI IRIA EL SELECT CON LOS DATOS DE LA INFORMACION DE LA CONSULTA SQL

```
        <tr>
          <td> <label for="email">Email</label>
          </td>
          <td> <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="submit" title="Registrarse" name="Registrarse">Registrarse</button>
    </form>
    <br />
    <a href="#" id="login-link">¿Ya tienes cuenta? Inicia sesión aquí</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a partir de que es tu propia estructura de carpetas y no la de un Framework (porque de ser así no tendrías problemas).

Lo que puedes hacer es definir una ruta raíz (root) y trabajar con ella.

```
<?php
define("ROOT", __DIR__ ."/");

echo ROOT;
// C:\laragon\www\backend\crud/
```

Luego mandas a llamarlo así:

```
<?php
include_once(ROOT ."config/config.php");

// Resultado
// C:\laragon\www\backend\crud/config/config.php
```

Yo por ejemplo, hago un archivo **loader** donde configuro mis rutas.

```
<?php

// Estoy en => domionio/root/
define('SLASH', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('DIR_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('DIR_CLASS', DIR_ROOT.SLASH.'class'.SLASH);
define('DIR_VIEWS', DIR_ROOT.SLASH.'views'.SLASH);
define('DIR_ASSETS', DIR_ROOT.SLASH.'assets'.SLASH);

require_once(DIR_ROOT.'algo.php');
require_once(DIR_CLASS.'database.php');
require_once(DIR_VIEWS.'login.php');
require_once(DIR_ASSETS.'helpers.php');

?>
```

De esa manera manejo mis archivos mas fácilmente. Tu decides que hacer.

Ojo al hecho que en todas defino como ultimo carácter la barra invertida " **/** ", y obviamente cuando llamo esas rutas definidas no pongo la barra antes del nombre del archivo `include_once(ROOT ."config/config.php");`

Comment: Si pero en el primer define echo ROOT;
// C:\laragon\www\backend\crud/ el resultado es C:\laragon\www\backend\crud\config, coge el archivo en el que esta

Comment: Queeeeeeee????????? No entiendo nada tu comentario...

Comment: Este es tu resultado de tu primer define:                                                                   C:\laragon\www\backend\crud, mi resultado coge el archivo en el que esta es decir backend\crud\config.. entiendes?, si quieres pego una captura para que lo veas

Comment: Pero te puse los dos ejemplos justo para que sepas cual es el que mas se ajusta a tu caso. Tu debes elegir donde vas a definir tus rutas globales. Obviamente si pones el primer código dentro de "config" te va a coger la carpeta config. El primer ejemplo es para hacerlo en el root, el segundo para hacerlo en otra carpeta. Entiendes ahora?? Es mas, en el segundo ejemplo comento que estoy en una carpeta llamada root `// Estoy en => domionio/root/`

Comment: si ya lo consegui, muchas gracias